# Корректно ли передавать поле экземпляра в метод экземпляра?

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть поле уровня экземпляра и какие-то методы экземпляра.

Корректно ли то, что я в некоторых участках программы передаю это поле, как параметр в метод или наиболее верно иметь какой-то отдельную версию метода, которая работает с поле на прямую?

```
  class ControlManager
    {
        Control _currentControl;
        FindConfig _config;
        bool TryFindControl(Control control,out Control result)
        {
          //Тут используется _config, но этот метод может вызываться, как при 
//обработке какого-то события, так и сюда в некоторых случаях может передаваться _currentControl
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вы передаете поле как папаметр в метод, то есть метод напрямую не использует состояние класса, вероятно, этот метод должен быть статическим и/или находиться где то в другом классе?

Comment: @tym32167 да, я вот тоже думал об этом.

Comment: Книгу "Рефакторинг" Фаулера читали? Там, в частности, автор как раз описывает, как в ходе рассуждений и рефакторинга он выносит члены одного класса в другой, потом часть возвращает обратно (но уже в переименованный класс)... Если ознакомитесь, - вероятно, сможете найти решение для своего случая.

Comment: Покажите свой код. Содержимое методов по большей части можете удалить. Важно видеть _названия_ классов, методов, полей. Возможно, мы подскажем, как лучше сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Дополнил.